# Live text change (Edittext)Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

On Edittext when user type something i am adding  "#" at last of line except for first line, also i add digits="1234567890#" to allow number only.
Here is code

```
tt = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
  }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    inter.removeTextChangedListener(tt);        
            String[] lines = inter.getText().toString().
            replace("#","").
            split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
            int row = 0;
            for(String st : lines){
                str.append(st+repeate("#",row)+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                row++;
            }
            inter.setText(str);
            inter.addTextChangedListener(tt);
        }
    };
```

But the problem with this is when user type any thing its cursor move to start of line.

Also when user press del on softkeyboard while cursor is in between "#" it should remove last digit of that line and cursor should move to its near.

Please help.

**EDIT**

Now cursor work fine except backspace key

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    android:digits="1234567890\n"
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    />



tt = new TextWatcher() {
        int select =0;
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            inter.setSelection(select);
            }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){       

            select = inter.getSelectionStart()+1;
        } 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            inter.removeTextChangedListener(tt);

            String[] lines = inter.getText().toString().
            replace("#","").
            split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            StringBuilder str= new StringBuilder();
            int row = 0;
            for(String st : lines){
                str.append(st+repeate("#",row)+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                row++;
            }
            inter.setText(str);
            inter.addTextChangedListener(tt);
        }
    };
    inter.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Comment: could you please share your xml?

Comment: @Akeshwar  post edited